# ddl in gridview need to get row values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've got a DDL in a gridview, and based on the user selection of the DDL I need to get values from the gridview such as the row id, row column1 and row column 2 values. my code in the gridview is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPO" runat="server" DataKeyNames="DC" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDataBound="gvPO_RowDataBound" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DC"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblDC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DC") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ped"><ItemTemplate><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPed" runat="server"SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Ped") %>' AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlPed_SelectedIndexChanged"  ><asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have other columns to get but the top two should be enough. My code in the code behind is as follows:

```
Protected Sub ddlPed_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim pedVal As String = TryCast(sender, DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value
   Dim dc As String = gvPO.FindControl("lblDC").ToString() 'returns nothing
   If (pedVal = "1") Then
      pnlPed.Visible = True 'this works as the panel is made visible
   End If
End Sub
```

I know that I need to get the row id which is the Id and/or can I use the datakey of DC for the row? Not sure how to get this data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your caode is not working because you're not doing the FindControl from the respective row of the gridview. Try

```
Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(ddl.NamingContainer, GridViewRow) 'your selected row
Dim lblDCA As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblDC"), Label) 'find any controls using the row object

....
```